# Mason: Request Payload

Tags: perl, rest, mason

I need to receive data, which comes in 'Request Payload' header, with [`Mason`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mason)-based Perl script.

I have tried `$r->body()`, `$r->upload()`, `$m->content()` methods, but they returns empty string.

The data in request exists, I have checked it with Chrome dev-tools.

Comment: Are you trying to read a header? Are you handling post data? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
my $raw_body;
$r->read($raw_body, $r->headers_in->{'Content-length'});
```